# Automatically deactivate link for attachments

Tags: attachments, links

It's probably super easy. I know it can be done when uploading stuffs to WP but I wonder if there is a simple snippet or setting to automatically deactivate link on attachment.

For example :

I do not want : `<a href=""><img src="" /></a>`but I want `<img src="" />`
I've veen thinking about a regex to do this but maybe there's a less tricky way to do that.

Hope this is not a duplicate, I've been searching on wpse, found nothing related.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With markup embedded into the content there is no less tricky way than regex to do it, save perhaps a [markup parser like SimpleHTMLDom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

```
function remove_image_link_102512($content) {
  $pattern = '|<a.*?href="(.*)".*>?(<img.*?/?>)(?:</a>)?|';
  $content = preg_replace($pattern,'$2',$content);
  return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content','remove_image_link_102512');
```

As with all regex + markup solutions, I'd test that thoroughly. Of course, as no saved data is updated it won't catastrophically or permanently break anything if it fails.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot. I was thinking about something that works with `wp_insert_post_data` but this snippet works !

Comment: You would need to do about the same with `wp_insert_post_data`. Altering the content on save, if that is an option, would mean less work for the server with the visitor loads the page. I am sure there are media hooks as well, but I do not know that subsystem especially well.